# Dynamically hiding controls in an ExtJS Fieldset

Tags: javascript, extjs, fieldset

Is there any event to hide some controls in fieldset based on checkbox check/uncheck events

thanks in advance

---

sample code for (Listner of Fieldset )

```
listeners: {
          collapse: function () {
            //debugger;
            if (Ext.getDom('chkWarrantyCover').checked == false) {
              Ext.getCmp("WarrantyFieldset").expand();
              Ext.getDom('chkWarrantyCover').checked = false
              Ext.getDom('btnComEdit').style.visibility = "hidden";
              Ext.getDom('btnEditPerson').style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
            else
              Ext.getCmp("WarrantyFieldset").expand();
          }
        },
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow!  Thank you for trying to add your example code.  Unfortunately you tried to edit it into someone else's answer, which isn't the best way.  I've migrated your example code into the body of your question.  If you need to make further improvements to your question, please use the "edit" link above and to the left of this message, below the tag list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using "onCheckClick" event for fieldset:

```
Code:onCheckClick: function () {
    if (Ext.getDom('chkWarrantyCover').checked == true) {
        Ext.getDom('btnComEdit').style.visibility = "visible";
        Ext.getDom('btnEditPerson').style.visibility = "visible";
        Ext.getDom('btnEditNotify').style.visibility = "visible";
}
 else {
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

In Extjs 4.0 there does not seem to be collapse/expand/onCheckClick events.  Not sure how this would be possible in 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the collapse/expand events on the fieldset, they will fire when the checkbox state changes.

Answer (score 0):

can you provide some sample codoe of what you are attempting to do? If not the listener is the most obvious answer. I would say do it on a select event and check for that on the checkbox id.
Usually you can get the state with Ext.getCmp()

Comment: please consider this a courtesy notification that @narasimha has provided sample code (albeit in a roundabout way).

Comment: sorry it was not there yesterday when I posted my comment. i'll look at it now.